# Python MySQL Programming Error:1064(42000), while making form using Flask

Tags: python, mysql, forms, flask-wtforms, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to make a form using Flask and upload the data of form to MySQL database and there I am encountering this error.

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

I used the following code:

```
if request.method=="POST" and form.validate():
        username=form.username.data
        email=form.email.data
        password=sha256_crypt.encrypt((str(form.password.data)))
        c,conn=connections()

        x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (%s)",
                      (thwart(username)))

        if int(x) > 0:
            flash("That username is already taken, please choose another")
            return render_template('register.html', form=form)

        else:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, tracking) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                      (thwart(username), thwart(password), thwart(email), thwart("/introduction-to-python-programming/")))

            conn.commit()
            flash("Thanks for registering!")
            c.close()
            conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting what `%s` is wrong, it should be like this

```py
x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (%s)" %
                      (thwart(username)))
```

or

```py
x = c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = {thwart(username))}")
```

Comment: This way the compiler is showing the error for invalid syntax

Comment: Well, this answer was wrong is it's nature, so I made a new one. You got the syntax error probably due to using an older version of python, f-strings were added in 3.6

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you have the `%s` in parentheses, the code it should look like this

```py
x = c.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s",
    (thwart(username),)
)
```

The `,` behind `thwart(username))` is mandatory and tells Python you want that to be a tuple of size 1, otherwise it would be interpreted as a string.